# How to perform html markups on site in Django

Tags: python, html, django

Recently I've started to learn Django, I've decided to make 
a sample blog website. I've made Post model which creates and publish post. But there's a problem, I've no idea how to attach html markups to my Post object's attribute for instance "text" e.g
I want to bold my text, but instead **text**, I see "`<b>text</b>`".
Here is how I've made Post model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    introduction = models.TextField()
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Why is storing html different from storing any other kind of data?

Comment: When I try to perform this data on my site for example bolded text, it shows <b>Text</b> instead **Text**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your template file use the [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter like this:

```
<h1>{{post.title | safe}}</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, That is what I was asking of.